# Finding an isomorphism between two rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How can I find the isomorphism between rings:
$ \Bbb Z [T] / (T^2-5T+6) $ and $ \Bbb Z^2 $?

$ \Bbb Z [T] / (T^2-5T+6) = \Bbb Z [T] / (T-3)(T-2) $.

Is it true that:

$\Bbb Z [T] / (T^2-5T+6) = \Bbb Z [T] / (T-2) \times  \Bbb Z [T] / (T-3)$ ?

Comment: Yes you are correct, this follows from Chinese Remainder Theorem:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way to find an isomorphism $$A/I\to B$$
for rings $A, B$ and an ideal $I$, is to find a surjection $$A\to B$$ which has kernel $I$.

In your situation you will hence want to find the right map
$$\mathbb Z[T]\to \mathbb Z^2$$

As a ring map you have to have $1\mapsto (1,1)$ and to get the right condition for the kernel you need $T\mapsto (3,2)$ (or $T\mapsto (2,3)$, which works just as good by symmetry). This is clearly surjective. Can you identify the kernel with $(T^2-5T+6)$?

Edit: You have seen that yourself that $(T^2-5T+6)\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(f)$. To see the other direction observe that you could write the same map as $P\mapsto (P(3), P(2))$ for any polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients. Thus you know two zeros of any $P$ in the kernel. Conclude that $T-3$ and $T-2$ must divide any such $P$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. +1

Comment: Okay. I can see that $f((T-3)(T-2)) = 0$ for any such map $f : \mathbb{Z}[T] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$. Thus $(T^2−5T+6) \subseteq \mathrm{ker} f$. How do we get the reverse inequality?